# How can i build projects in a solution in a certain order using MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have the following msbuild  command line:
    msbuild test.sln /t:project8;project5;project1;project9;project10;project20;project2 /p:Configuration="Release" /p:OutputPath=C:\ProjectDlls

Will this build them in the order specified ?  or can I specify order as in the Visual Studio IDE )right click on sln and Build Order)

I want to build in the following order 
project1
project8
project10
project20
project2
project9
project5

Comment: Hi, what's the relationship(project reference, project dependency) between those projects mentioned in your question? It matters a lot to affect the real order to run :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this build them in the order specified ?

If these projects don't have dependencies between them. They will run the order as you set in command. (For VS2017, it works)

For VS2017 and VS2019(msbuild 15.0,16.0):

```
msbuild test.sln /t:project1;project8;project10;project20;project2;project9;project5 /p:Configuration="Release" /p:OutputPath=C:\ProjectDlls /m:1
```

If you use this command, they will execute in the order you want.(If you don't add project references or project dependencies in other order!)

And add the `/m:1` to make sure the projects are built one by one.

> I want to build in the following order project1 project8 project10
>   project20 project2 project9 project5.

Apart from specify the order in command, you can specify the project dependency or project reference between those projects.

And msbuild(15.0 and above) will recognize the relationship between the projects and build the projects in an order that matched the relationship.

So actually the order in command, project dependencies, project references all affect the real build order. Avoid using all these 3 ways to set the order, it may mess up the build...

Answer (score -1):

Specifying the order on the command line as shown above, is **always** wrong. I've never seen this before, and it's like a bandaid. It just covers the real problem.

Instead you should use one of the following:

1. Specify the build order in visual studio, right click on the solution, select 'build order'.
2. Use Project References's to specify that one project depends on another.